# Syntax error for else and elif (Can't determine if structure issue)

Tags: python-2.7

I'm very new to python and I've been working on a basic calculator within python for the last few hours (rhetorical I know, given what python has built in, but it's part of my learning process), I've run into an error I can't seem to fix, generally I'm able to get my scripts on their feet and running with the assistance of a couple of Google searches but this one has me stumped. I'm getting a syntax error where I have an else, and while at first I was pretty sure it was a structure issue, rewriting the script didn't fix anything, vague I know, so here's the script (I've marked the spot with a comment) :

```
def Calculator():
tempnums = [] #stores nums only
tempfuncs = [] #stores funcs only
tmpfuncs = {} #stores funcs only
times = lambda multiply: tempnums[0]*tempnums[1]
div = lambda divide: tempnums[0]%tempnums[1]
plus = lambda add: tempnums[0]+tempnums[1]
minus = lambda subtract:tempnums[0]-tempnums[1]
done = 0
varnum = 0
xtimes = 0
divtimes = 0
plustimes = 0
mintimes = 0
while done == 0: #USER INPUT PROCESS
    varnum = varnum + 1
    tempint = input() #nums
    exec("num%d = tempint" % (varnum))
    function = raw_input() #functions
    if function != "=":
        if function == 'x':
            if x not in tmpfuncs:
                xtimes = xtimes + 1
                tmpfuncs[x] = times
            else:
                xtimes = xtimes + 1
                exec("tmpfuncs[x%d] = times" % (xtimes)
        else: #ERROR COMES HERE
            if function == '//':
                if dv not in tmpfuncs:
                    divtimes = divtimes + 1
                    tmpfuncs[dv] = div
                else:
                    divtimes = divtimes + 1
                    exec("tmpfuncs[dv%d] = div" % (divtimes)
            if function == '+':
                if pls not in tmpfuncs:
                    plustimes = plustimes + 1
                    tmpfuncs[pls] = plus
                else:
                    plustimes = plustimes + 1
                    exec("tmpfuncs[pls%d] = plus" % (plustimes)
            if function == '-':
                if mn not in tmpfuncs:
                    mintimes = mintimes + 1
                    tmpfuncs[mn] = minus
                else:
                    mintimes = mintimes + 1
                    exec("tmpfuncs[mn%d] = minus" % (mintimes)
    else: #user has selected to calculate input
        done = 1
        for i in range(1, varnum + 1):
            exec("tempnums.append(num%d)" % (i)) #adding nums to a list with dynamic var names
        print tmpfuncs
#next we'll make it so that tempnums[0] is the changing result as we use tempnums 0 and 1 to calculate the answer, deleting one as we go until there is only zero
        Calculator()
```

Calculator()

I'm hoping this is legible as I'm posting from mobile (as a matter of fact I'm writing this from mobile as well).

Answer (score 0):

The line above the `else` is missing a closing parens:

```
exec("tmpfuncs[x%d] = times" % (xtimes)
```

should be

```
exec("tmpfuncs[x%d] = times" % (xtimes))
```

The same error occurs in many other of your `exec` lines. Also, I suggest you consider restructuring your code so you do not need to use `exec` at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I don't know how I missed that twice.